# Пагинация retrofit2

Tags: retrofit2, pagination, paging

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать пагинацию?
Есть ссылка на страницу, которую парсим через ретрофит:
https://developerslife.ru/latest/0?json=true
На каждой странице 5 элементов, соответственно индекс с 0 по 4.
Как программно перейти на 2, 3 и т.д страницу?
У меня нету RecyclerView, в созданный в ручную список Mutable ArrayList  добавляю объекты по кнопке Next (ImageButton).

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я использую библиотеку Retrofit2 для парсинга информации с приведенной ссылки со страницей 0 (продублирую ссылку  https://developerslife.ru/latest/0?json=true). На каждой странице получается по 4 элемента, в данном случае по 4 гифки. Вопрос как перейти на 1 страницу, вторую и так далее. Я получаю ошибку  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5

Comment: С вопросом разобрался.